# Do Objects name influence their behavior?

Tags: java, swing, object, nullpointerexception, initialization

I am very certain, that naming an object does not change anything about it like

```
A a = new A();
A b = new A();
```

The second object should have the exact same attributes as the first object. So here is my coding problem

```
public class Animation {

public static final Animation MOROTE_SEOI_NAGE = new Animation(JudokaComponent.MOROTE1, JudokaComponent.MOROTE2, JudokaComponent.MOROTE3);
public static final Animation morote_seoi_nage = new Animation(JudokaComponent.judokaStanding1, JudokaComponent.judokaStanding2, JudokaComponent.judokaStanding1);

public static final Animation UCHI_MATA = new Animation(JudokaComponent.uchiMata1, JudokaComponent.uchiMata2, JudokaComponent.uchiMata3);
public static final Animation uchi_mata = new Animation(JudokaComponent.judokaStanding1, JudokaComponent.judokaStanding2, JudokaComponent.judokaStanding1);

public static final Animation O_SOTO_GARI = new Animation(JudokaComponent.oSotoGari1, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari2, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari3);
public static final Animation Lel = new Animation(JudokaComponent.oSotoGari1, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari2, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari3);
public static final Animation o_soto_gari = new Animation(JudokaComponent.judokaStanding1, JudokaComponent.judokaStanding2, JudokaComponent.judokaStanding1);


public int ID;
public BufferedImage[] SPRITES;

public Animation(BufferedImage step1, BufferedImage step2, BufferedImage step3){
    if(step1 == null || step2 == null || step3 == null) {
        if(step1 == null) System.err.print("Step 1 was NPE. Address: " + this + "\n");
        if(step2 == null) System.err.print("Step 2 was NPE. Address: " + this + "\n");
        if(step3 == null) System.err.print("Step 3 was NPE. Address: " + this + "\n");
        throw new RuntimeException("Animation NEP");
    }
    BufferedImage[] SPRITES = {step1, step2, step3};
    this.SPRITES = SPRITES;
}


}
```

To be more specific theese lines here:

```
public static final Animation O_SOTO_GARI = new Animation(JudokaComponent.oSotoGari1, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari2, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari3);
public static final Animation Lel = new Animation(JudokaComponent.oSotoGari1, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari2, JudokaComponent.oSotoGari3);
```

To me they look like the EXACT same object, but with different names. When i run the code WITHOUT the O_SOTO_GARI object it works as intended, the startup atleast. But, once I un-comment the O_SOTO GARI object creation I get this output before the game starts:

```
Step 1 was NPE. Address: com.kruhlmann.judoka.graphics.Animation@184ec44
Step 2 was NPE. Address: com.kruhlmann.judoka.graphics.Animation@184ec44
Step 3 was NPE. Address: com.kruhlmann.judoka.graphics.Animation@184ec44
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

But why? If I make the exact same object and call it "Lel", i do not get this error. Why is this happening, I am so confused